# Examine Element That is Removed onblur

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So I have an element that is dynamically added to the page with Javascript. After it is added, it is granted focus.

I want to examine the element in chrome dev tools, but the issue is that it has a onblur event handler that removes it from the DOM. So basically when I click on the dev tools to select the element, it is removed. An example can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/MSZEx/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <button id="the_button">Click me to show field</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#the_button").click(function() {
    $elt = $("<input>").attr("type", "text").attr("id", "text_field");
    $("#container").append($elt);
    $elt.focus();
    $elt.blur(function() {
       $elt.remove(); 
    });
});
```

In the example I would like to be able to examine the input element that shows up once the button is clicked.

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the `$elt.remove();` line.

Comment: @blgt So that is definitely generally possible, but what if my Javascript was very very long, and it was minified. If you post an answer I will select it if there is not a better solution presented by someone else.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Rightclick the node in the element tree -> Break on... -> Node Removal.

The debugger will now break before the node gets removed.

Comment: The question was about how to get to the point where you are able to do that. eg. in OP's fiddle, you'll lose focus (thus removing the element) when you right-click inside the element tree.

Comment: @blgt When the developer tools are already open and you expand the parent node before clicking the button in the fiddle, you can right click the textbox node and setup the break on node removal. Works for me.

Comment: @darthmaim What chrome version are you running? I can't replicate (chrome 35.0 under Win8)

Comment: @blgt Was chrome 35 on mac at work, here at home on windows 7 i can't replicate it either.

Comment: This is the accepted anser, but apparently doesnt work on windows (same here) - I think that should clearly be stated within the answer.

Answer (score 51):

All of these answers didn't really work for me.

At the time of writing (Chrome 92) you can use the `Rendering` settings in Chrome Dev Tools:

**`Open Chrome Dev Tools`** > **`Click the kebab menu`** > **`More tools dropdown`** > **`Rendering`** > **`Check emulate a focused page`**

This keeps the focus enabled whilst playing around in Chrome Dev Tools

Edit: 20/01/2024 - this is still the case in Chrome 120

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  It's a permanent solution that does exactly what I want it to

Comment: This is the best answer. Thanks!

Comment: Well it's not «permanent» in a way that it only works for the current tab, it seems. But still a good solution.

Answer (score 26):

I got it working by right clicking the parent node in the tree without focus & then

-> Break on... -> Subtree Modifications

Note that a page refresh doesn't clear this out, so might have to close & reopen the inspector if you have forgotten where you put your break point

Comment: You can also find breakpoints like these in DOM Breakpoints in the right panel.

Comment: In order to even find the parent node I also had to set a timed breakpoint using the console. (1) `setTimeout(() => {debugger;}, 3000` (2) you have 3 second to make the thing appear (3) execution is frozen so you can dig through the DOM tree in the inspector to find the node.

Answer (score 7):

The trick I like to use is

- Open up the sources panel
- Display the tooltip
- Use the keyboard shortcut to pause script execution. (Hover over the pause icon to find out the keyboard shortcut)
- When the script execution is paused, go back to the Elements panel and inspect the tooltip as you are used to

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to open Chrome dev tools, focus the element in question in the browser viewport and then hit <kbd>F8</kbd> which will stop all JS from running (without losing focus), leaving the element even after it loses focus till you enable JS again. This way you can inspect the element in the DOM tree and proceed from there.

Enable JS by hitting <kbd>F8</kbd> again.

Answer (score 3):

"but what if my Javascript was very very long, and it was minified" <- In this case, you could try this (use F12 to trigger):

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) { if (e.keyCode == 123) debugger; });
// Or in vanilla JS:
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => { if (e.keyCode == 123) debugger; })
```

[in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MSZEx/1/)

[As suggested by this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/249050/chrome-keyboard-shortcut-to-pause-script-execution)

I don't know if it works in chrome, but it does in Firefox when you already have a console open.

Comment: In some scenarios this is the only solution

Answer (score 3):

How about you just simulate the click from the console?

Open your f12 tools on the website, get the elements id and do your own `$("#the_button").click()`. The console will keep the focus so your element won't blur. You can then go to the elements tab and look at the css.

Comment: You mean edit the Javascript file in the developer's console?

Comment: No, don't touch their javascript file. Instead of trying to right click and inspect element, just find the elements name, enter in the developer console the command to simulate a click on it, and then find the element in the elements tab. So long as you stay within the developer tools the element shouldn't blur.

Comment: I believe if you try this in my fiddle you will see it will not work. The element is only created when the button is clicked and then the input is immediately granted focus.

Comment: I tried it with your fiddle and it did work. Go to your fiddle -> open developer console -> change scope for the console from '<top_frame>' to 'result(...' -> enter the command `$("#the_button").click()` in the console (the element will be created but not take focus) -> go to elements tab and investigate the css.

Answer (score 2):

According to the
[Chrome DevTools Keyboard Shortcuts](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts) page, <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+C</kbd> toggles Inspect Element Mode, which allows you to hover over the element without it disappearing, and this will sync with the Elements view in the DevTools. However, as soon as you click on the element, it will still disappear.

You can combine this with the other answers to break immediately (using <kbd>F8</kbd> or Ctrl+</kbd> to pause script execution) or on modification of the element/subtree (which should now be shown in the Elements view).

In Firefox this does not work, but you can still use the trick with setting a breakpoint (Debugger -> Event Listener Breakpoints -> blur). You can then select the element while the page is paused.

Comment: If I do this in Firefox, the element does disappear.

Comment: @aross Chrome ≠ Firefox. But the breakpoint trick still works, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If putting a break-point is an acceptable solution for you (which it seems to be according to comments) then you can add a debugger; statement to automatically halt execution. For more information check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Comment: As my comment above stated, I am also interested in other solutions as this would be almost impossible if I was on another person's site and they had just one long minified Javascript file.

Comment: Well, I've had mixed success in the past with detaching the debugging tools from the main browser window. Because if you click the "Examine element" button in the detached window, the onblur-javascript might not be executed, because it's the whole browser window that loses focus. Again, your mileage may vary...

Comment: With lots of DOM operations this is still unpractical or even impossible.